# Fail to post(CURL) the form to EPayment GatewayFail to post(CURL) the form to EPayment Gateway

Tags: php, html, database, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Here is a donation page .

I tried to save the data to MYSQL db and curl the essential info to the EPayment Gateway(Paydollar) ,e.g. merchantId ,amount ,currCode....

If I activate the `<form name="payFormCcard"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">`,it will jump to the db storage and will not do the epayment action .

If I activate the `<form action="https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp" id="payFormCcard" method="post" name="payFormCcard">` ,it won't do the MYSQL storage .

---

Now ,  I blind both  form action methods :`<form name="payFormCcard"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">` &  `<form action="https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp" id="payFormCcard" method="post" name="payFormCcard">`, no submit actions will be done .

It seems that it cannot pass the parameters to the EPayment Gateway by POST-CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

=>It seems that this code cannot be activated .

How  should I fix the code?

> create.php

```
 <?php
// Include config file
require_once 'database.php';
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=big5");
print_r($_POST);

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$CName = $Address = $Phone = $Amount= $Purpose= $Ticket = "";
$CName_err = $Address_err = $Phone_err = $Amount_err = $Purpose_err = $Ticket_err="";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Validate name
    $input_CName = trim($_POST["CName"]);
    if (empty($input_CName)) {
        $CName_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif (!filter_var(trim($_POST["CName"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z'-.\s ]+$/")))) {
        $CName_err = 'Please enter a valid name.';
    } else {
        $CName = $input_CName;
    }

    // Validate address
    $input_Address = trim($_POST["Address"]);
    if (empty($input_Address)) {
        $Address_err = 'Please enter an address.';
    } else {
        $Address = $input_Address;
    }
    // Validate Phone
    $input_Phone = trim($_POST["Phone"]);
    if (empty($input_Phone)) {
        $Phone_err = "Please enter your phone number again.";
    } elseif (!ctype_digit($input_Phone)) {
        $Phone_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
    } else {
        $Phone = $input_Phone;
    }

    // Validate Amount
    $input_Amount = trim($_POST["Amount"]);
    if (empty($input_Amount)) {
        $Amount_err = "Please enter the amount.";
    } elseif (!ctype_digit($input_Amount)) {
        $Amount_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
    } else {
        $Amount = $input_Amount;
    }



    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if (empty($CName_err) && empty($Address_err) && empty($Amount_err) && empty($Phone_err)) {
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO donation (CName, Address, Phone, Amount ,Ticket, Purpose) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?, ?)";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($CName, $Address, $Phone, $Amount ,$Ticket ,$Purpose));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array (
           'merchantId'   => 'sth',
            'orderRef'    => 'sth',
            'currCode'   => 'sth',
            'mpsMode'    => 'NIL',
       'successUrl' =>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Success.html',
 'failUrl' =>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Fail.html',
'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Cancel.html',
            'payType'    =>'sth',
            'lang'       =>'sth',
            'payMethod'  => 'sth',
            'secureHash'=> 'sth'
        )));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);


}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<html lang="en">-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>

        </title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
                 .wrapper{
                     width: 500px;
                     margin: 0 auto;
                 }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h2>
                                form
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <p>

                        </p><br>
                        <p>

                        </p><!--                 <form name="payFormCcard"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> -->
                <!--        <form action="https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp" id="payFormCcard" method="post" name="payFormCcard"> -->

                            <div class="form-group &lt;?php echo (!empty($CName_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?&gt;">
                                <label>*English Name</label> <input class="form-control" name="CName" type="text" value="<?php echo $CName; ?>"> <span class="help-block"><?php echo $CName_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group &lt;?php echo (!empty($Phone_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?&gt;">
                                <label>*Contact No.</label> <input class="form-control" name="Phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>"> <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Phone_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group &lt;?php echo (!empty($Address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?&gt;">
                                <label>* Email Address</label> 
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="Address"><?php echo $Address; ?></textarea> <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Address_err; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group &lt;?php echo (!empty($Amount_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?&gt;">
                                <label>*Donation Amount</label> <input class="form-control" list="Amount" multiple name="Amount"> <datalist id="Amount">
                                    <option value="100">
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="300">
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="500">
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="1000">
                                    </option>
                                </datalist> <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Amount_err; ?></span>
                            </div>

                            </div><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php">Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                        <p>

                        </p><br>
                        <p>
                            Thank you for your support
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro it says merchantId parameter incorrect, just put the correct one, just consult their manual

Comment: @Ghost But in view of coding(syntax) , is it working ?

Comment: look okay on this end, if the server response says `Parameter merchantId Incorrect` check the parameters of your request, might need fixing

Comment: @Ghost I have modified my question . I blind the post action methods . After I click the submit button , no actions is done .It cannot curl to the Payment Gateway .